# Как узнать, какой шрифт платный, а какой нет?

Tags: шрифты, ttf

Как узнать, какой шрифт платный, а какой нет?

Comment: наверное, это в области юриспруденции

Comment: Тот за который денег просят - тот и платный.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотреть на лицензию, по которой он распростроняется.

Comment: Как вариант зайти на http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ и там смотреть всю инфу по шрифту

Answer (score 0):

Саму лицензию шрифта можно узнать встроенными средствами Windows. Правой кнопкой мыши кликаем по нужному шрифту — «Свойства», смотрим содержимое  «License», иногда необходимая информация оказывается в «Description». Если по каким-то причинам свойства не отображаются как на картинке ниже, скачиваем и устанавливаем Font properties extension [с официального сайта Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/TrueTypeProperty21.mspx). Спасибо.

[image: Kira.otf]